# Disable click outside of bootstrap modal area only for a few second

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I have a Boostrap modal that pops-up when a user reaches a webpage.

I'd like to prevent, **only for a few seconds**, users closing the modal, by clicking outside of it. After that time the user will regain the ability to close it in that manner.

At this point, I've been able to prevent users to close the modal but, unfortunately, I've been unsuccessful reverting this behaviour after a set time.

So far, I've tried disabling the click-outside function by doing:

```
$('#my-modal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
});
```

Then showing the modal

```
$('#final-taunt-modal-1').modal('show');
```

Up to here everything works as expected not allowing the user to close the modal.
Then I'd tried to give the ability to close the modal by setting a timeout:

```
setTimeout( function() {
    $('#my-modal').modal({
        backdrop: true, // I've tried writing 'true' as a string with the same effect here. 
        keyboard: false
    });
}, 4500);
```

The result is that the user can indeed close the modal with the keyboard by typing 'ESC' but the modal doesn't close when the user clicks outside it.

I've also tried to set the modal options via data-attributes in the HTML elements like:

```
<div tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static" class="modal" id="my-modal" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
```

and then giving the ability to close the modal doing as below, just to get the same outcome.

```
$('#my-modal').attr('data-backdrop', true)
```

Any advice to get the result I want? (I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7)

Comment: Why not just disable this behaviour and then enable the close behaviour by binding a custom event handler that triggers the click on a close icon or the ESC key?

Comment: You can change the backdrop setting using `$('#myModal').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = false;`

Comment: @NisargShah that solved my issue. Still I couldn't allow for the modal to be closed with Escape, but it's not something I really need. Thanks for your help.